# Importing an Image into Visual Studio to Code

Tags: vb.net, image, visual-studio, silverlight, expression-blend

I don't feel as if what I'm asking is ridiculous. Would I be able to import an image of any kind (png, jpeg, etc) into visual studio and then define regions/hotspots to code as buttons? It would kind of be like an expression blend/silverlight thing but if I already had the design in an image format and I just need to put code behind it.

Comment: How complex are your hotspot shapes/regions going to be?

Answer (score 0):

Expression Studio contains tools that can meet your requirements,

http://www.microsoft.com/expression/products/Design_WhatIsExpressionDesign.aspx

For example, by using Design, you can import existing images and export XAML directly, which can later be used in your Visual Studio/Expression Blend projects.

You have to use such separate tools, such as Visual Studio does not have such features built in.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this with an imagemap and hotspots over button graphics in an image the aspx page.